# Utilizing subqueries in sql. Displaying no output

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a task of retrieving the first and last names of customers where their orders have not shipped out. Below is the tables made to get this result ↓↓↓

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    employee_id INT NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    manager_id INT,

    CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
    CONSTRAINT emp_fk_mgr 
        FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees(employee_id) 
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    order_date DATE NOT NULL,
    shipped_date DATE,
    employee_id INT,

    CONSTRAINT orders_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
    CONSTRAINT orders_fk_customers
        FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
    CONSTRAINT orders_fk_employees
        FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
);

CREATE TABLE order_details
(
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    item_id INT NOT NULL,
    order_qty INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT order_details_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_id, item_id),
    CONSTRAINT order_details_fk_orders
        FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (order_id),
    CONSTRAINT order_details_fk_items
        FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (item_id)
);
```

Currently, I have the following query made up, but it keeps generating No Output.

```
SELECT c.customer_first_name
FROM order_details od
JOIN orders o ON od.order_id = o.order_id
JOIN customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_id IN (SELECT shipped_date FROM orders WHERE shipped_date IS NULL);
```

Can someone help me to get the result I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, your customers are not dates and you actually intend:

```
WHERE c.customer_id IN (SELECT o.customer_id FROM orders o WHERE shipped_date IS NULL)
```

Comment: @EricFranklin: I am surprised that your DBMS even allowed you to compare a `DATE` value to an `integer` - which DBMS product are you using? Postgres and Oracle will flat out refuse to run that statement